# Spring-security login page redirect not working in Chromium/Chrome

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am preparing a project for students in my class with Spring Boot (including Spring Security) + Thymeleaf. It's really simple at the beginning, but I ran into trouble with Chromium/Chrome for the default login page.

This is my Spring Security Configuration:

```
 @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/assets/**", "/", "/login**", "/logout**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
        .and().formLogin().and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/").permitAll();
    http.csrf().disable();
    http.headers().frameOptions().disable();
  }
```

As you can see, my landing page can be accessed without authentification. It contains a login button like this (I'm using Thymeleaf):

```
  <form th:unless="${user}" th:action="@{/login}" method="get">
    <input type="submit" value="Login" />
  </form>
```

I also tried to add it without using Thymeleaf tags like this:

```
  <form action="/login" method="get">
    <input type="submit" value="Login" />
  </form>
```

When I run the application, I can access the landing page on both, Firefox and Chromium under http://localhost:8080. 
When I click the login button, the behaviour differs:

- Firefox sends a GET to "http://localhost:8080/login" and Spring Security's login page opens.
- Chromium/Chrome sends a GET to "http://localhost:8080/login?" and I get a 404. If I remove the question mark, the login page appears.

So, is there anything I did wrong? Can I format my form not to send an empty query? Can I configure Spring Security to accept that empty query?

I already thought about making the login button a simple link, but I'd like to avoid the confusion between links forms and use buttons in forms. Also, I am curious whether there is a better solution.

Comment: Why are using a form to do a GET request?

Comment: That's because I wanted to use a button for both login and logout. I know I can make a link look like a button with styling, but do I have to go that way? Why does it make a difference for spring security whether I add a "?" do a path?

Comment: The point with login pages is that you show the login page with a get request but you send the credentials with a post. Your problem is that you send an empty GET request (which makes no sense) and this could behave different in different browsers. Add data to your request. And if you send credentials use POST.

Comment: If I understand correctly, using a link also sends sn empty get request, so the difference between using a link and using a form wit a get action is almost nonexistent. It should be ok to navigate by form, and it perfectly works with Spring MVC in general. The form submit only differs in the “?“ which is not sent by FF, but with Chromium. I understand that Chromium is doing this correctly (according to the HTML spec), but Spring security seems to have a problem with query parameters. Even if I add parameters (other than ?error), the request is not matched by SS at all.